# How to import geometry data from csv file to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, csv, import, database

I have geometry file in *.xls file, but when I save in *.csv it say "some feature in your workbook might be lost if you save it as CSV (Comma delimited)" however I keep that file anyway and when I import that file in postgres it say "ERROR: extra data after last expected column". Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the two messages are separate.  The first message is just a warning that anything such as formulae, formatting and additional worksheets cannot be saved in a CSV as it is a simple ascii format.  The second message suggests that you maybe have a text field as one of your attributes which contains a comma.  This will effectively introduce an extra column break partway through the text field, hence the message about extra data after the last expected column.  I recommend that you do a global search and replace to change all commas something else like a full-stop or a hyphen.  You could also use a semicolon so long as you are sure that wont get interpreted as a column delimiter (it is sometimes used that way).

Comment: yeah, I did the search and found three commas from nowhere that confused my delimeter.